# Visual Studio 2013: Is it possible to access Work Items that are in a different project?

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2013

We are in the process of migrating from TFS Version Control to Git (hosted on TFS 2013).

Is it possible to create a new git-versioned project and put all of our source code in there, but still use the old project for work items?

Specifically, I would like to be able to be using my "new" (git) project in Visual Studio 2013, and click on Team Explorer / Work Items, and have that connect to my "old" project work items.

Answer (score 0):

In your queries, use the 'Team Project' field and specify (have to type by hand, no auto-complete) the name of your other team project.

Or for (very) simple work item migration, assuming the same, un-modified process templates, and you're not terribly interested in the history of the work items, use the excel integration to output a list of work items, then re-import.  Ignore closed items, then items in the initial state will migrate fine, but you'll have to move the other items through their states to get to the desired state.  This is fairly easy through the excel integration, as long as you bring up the 'desired' state, but the whole process is a pretty big PITA, so I'd use the first solution if possible.